Checking if a position is legal with a chess engine
Are there chess engines that can automatically check with certainty if a given chess position is illegal, i.e. can't be reached from the starting position with legal moves? If a position is legal, providing a sample game leading to that position is enough as a proof. However, proving that a position is illegal can be much more difficult. I suppose that for the majority of positions such proofs simply do not exist, but can a computer solve this problem? Are there AI engines capable of retrograde analysis?

(Duplicate?) Big NO. A whole genre of problem chess depends on this question, and the positions can be murderously difficult.
There does exist software like Natch or Jacobi trying to give you a
proof game for a position, but even those must throw the towel
if it gets too complicated. At the moment, an experienced human will beat any AI when it comes to legality.

Why duplicate? Do you have a reference to the same question already asked? Perhaps any references to where this question was discussed?

I also heard about Retractor, Natch, and Euklide,  but they only try to prove that a position is legal and are useless in proving it illegal, as I understand. That's what my question was about.

Why is the task of winning a chess game easier for an AI than the task of reaching a certain position?

@Vosoni the estimated game-tree complexity for chess is huge. It's impossible for a computer to build the tree to find a certain position.

So is the forward tree :-) OP has a point there - it would be interesting if some AI could "learn" illegal positions. It must run in "intelligent" mode, since indeed running the back tree is impossible. TLDR: It hasn't been tried yet, it would be an interesting project.
